# How to redirect echo to txt in php?

Tags: php, ip

Hi I am trying to write the Ip addresses visiting my website onto a log file. Here's my code:

```
function getRealIpAddr(){
 if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ) {
  // Check IP from internet.
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
 } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ) {
  // Check IP is passed from proxy.
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
 } else {
  // Get IP address from remote address.
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 }
 return $ip;
}

echo getRealIpAddr();
```

I would like to get "echo getRealIpAddr();" onto an "iplogs.txt" that I have created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND)`. `FILE_APPEND` will not overwrite previous data.

Read [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

So in your case the codes are

```
$ip = getRealIpAddr();
$filename = '/full/path/to/iplogs.txt';
file_put_contents($filename, $ip, FILE_APPEND)
```

You can add line breaks with `\r\n` or `PHP_EOL` like this

```
file_put_contents($filename, $ip . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, I've added PHP_EOL to $ip, and it gives the last IP on the first line.

Comment: FILE_APPEND should add the content to the end of the file. Check Example #2 in the docs

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have a double-check, and it's at the end. However, it's a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Use the php function `file_put_contents`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
<?php
$file = 'iplogs.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new output to the file
$current .= getRealIpAddr();
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the file; reading the entire file before writing to it would be a bad resource intensive idea.